# Python: Pivot table with groupby counting of category

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a file that looks like:

```
+---------+---------+-------+
| Product | Quality | Origin|
+---------+---------+-------+
| Apple   | Good    |       |
+---------+---------+-------+
| Apple   | Bad     |       |
+---------+---------+-------+
| Apple   | Bad     |       |
+---------+---------+-------+
| Orange  | Good    |       |
+---------+---------+-------+
| .       |         |       |
+---------+---------+-------+
| .       |         |       |
+---------+---------+-------+
| Grape   | Good    |       |
+---------+---------+-------+
```

I want to make a pivot result with counts:

```
+---------+---------------+------+-----+
| Product | Total Number  | Good | Bad |
+---------+---------------+------+-----+
| Apple   | 5             | 3    | 2   |
+---------+---------------+------+-----+
| Orange  | 8             | 5    | 3   |
+---------+---------------+------+-----+
| Grape   | 3             | 1    | 2   |
+---------+---------------+------+-----+
| Total   | 16            | 9    | 7   |
+---------+---------------+------+-----+
```

I am using `groupby` and `count` to get the total number:

```py
Total_Product = ProdcutFile.groupby('Product').count()
```

But I how I can make the result table contain Good and Bad counts?

Comment: `df.melt(id_vars='Product','value_vars=['Good','Bad'])`?

Comment: `df.groupby(['Product', 'Quality']).size().unstack()` then add the total `df['total'] = df.sum(axis=1)`

Comment: You can add a totals row to the bottom of @RichieV's solution with this: `df.loc['Totals'] = df.sum()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way, using assign and pivot table.  The assign statement makes a column of ones, and summing this up provides the counts in the final table.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = '''Product  Quality 
Apple    Good    
Apple    Bad     
Apple    Bad     
Orange   Good
Orange   Bad
Grape    Good    
'''

df = (pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+', engine='python')
        .assign(counter = 1)
        .pivot_table(index='Product', 
                     columns='Quality', 
                     values='counter', 
                     aggfunc=sum, 
                     fill_value=0, 
                     margins=True, 
                     margins_name='Totals')
     )
print(df)

Quality  Bad  Good  Totals
Product                   
Apple      2     1       3
Grape      0     1       1
Orange     1     1       2
Totals     3     3       6
```

(Providing the columns names and ordering is straightforward and not shown.)

Comment: Thank you! the idea helped me to get the solution i wanted for my actual project!

Comment: Great!  Please consider clicking the green check-mark, to mark this as the accepted answer.  Thanks.